# Why is Laravel's App::getLocale() method inconsistent?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using 2 languages in my Laravel 5.2 app. There is a simple password-reminder page I'm implementing currently, and for reasons unknown to me I have problems in sending the new-password email in the correct language.

Let's say I see the page in German. In the view of the page, I echo 2 values, using Facades:

```
echo App::getLocale();
echo Session::get('locale');
```

The page is served in German, so **both** values echo `de`.

Now, I enter an email address into the form and submit it. The input gets to a controller method and calls a library to send a new password to the user:

```
public function resetPassword() {
    // Validate the input, retrieve the user...    

    Mailer::sendNewPasswordEmail($user); // Call to the library sending emails
}
```

Finally, in the library, I var_dump the same 2 values, like this:

```
public static function sendNewPasswordEmail($user) {
    var_dump(App::getLocale());
    var_dump(Session::get('locale'));
    die;
}
```

In this case, `Session::get('locale')` still equals `de`, but `App::getLocale()` shows `en`.

Why, why, why?

In my email template, I'm using the Blade's `@lang()` directive. As far as I know, the directive checks the application locale to determine which translation to serve. In my case, the email is being sent always in English and I have no clue why `App::getLocale()` returns a different value in the view and during the next POST request I'm making.

This is not the first time this happens, btw. At times is seems that views "know" more about the actual application locale, than the controllers, models or libraries. Confusing.

Ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Laravel 5.2 App_Locale is not persistent. the only way I've found to make locales work properlly is creating a middleware that calls App::setLocale() like this:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Session;
use App;
use Config;

class Locale {

   /**
    * Handle an incoming request.
    *
    * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
    * @param  \Closure  $next
    * @return mixed
    */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        App::setLocale(Session::get('locale'));
        return $next($request);
    }

}
```

Register your middleware on **Kernel.php**

```
protected $middleware = [
    .
    .
    .

   'App\Http\Middleware\Locale'
];
```

Comment: Sure, I considered this but you end up setting the app locale on every request. Thing is, the locale, after it's been set once, should keep its value, unless another value is used. Also, the way you do this suggests that it would be better to just rely on a custom Session variable, instead of using the Session to set something that refuses to be persistent.

Comment: If you find any solution please share it... Thanks.

Comment: In the end, I did not find a better way to keep the Session and App's locale in sync, so I did just that.

Comment: how can i set locale in route file by default ?